# Rails have to create a "fake" column in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In my tabel I have:

```
rating_score => The current score
ratings => The number of ratings which led to the score
```

I want to create a "fake" column named rating which is (rating_score/ratings) in model. That I can use in my controller to order after and in my view.

How should I create this in my model?

Comment: Those things are called `computed columns` or `calculated columns`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that you cannot have the SQL query order your results by a virtual attribute.
What you can do is just define the method like this in your model:

```
def rating
  rating_scope / ratings
end
```

and order your resultset in ruby based on the value:

```
results.sort_by(&:rating)
```

Comment: If you do need to persist the value, create a column for the value (as you would normally) and then in a `before_save` filter in the model, compute the value.

Comment: I some cases my ratings column are 0. Is it a problem?

Comment: @tzown: You can't divide by zero, so yes, this will be a problem. Just check for that case (and any others!) inside the `rating` method and return a value as necessary (e.g. `ratings == 0 ? 0 : rating_scope / ratings`).